# I can stop the timer, when I click the pause button, but when I click play again, 2 timers are playing and it is buggy

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I can stop the timer, when I click the pause button, but when I click play again, 2 timers are playing and it is buggy. It should resume the timer where it was paused.

```js
let timerSelection = 'Work';
let startingMinutes = 25;
let startingSeconds = 0;
let timerRunning;
let stopTimer;
let playing = false;
let currentMinutes;
let currentSeconds;

//sets the correct timer duration
function setWork() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 25;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'Work'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '25';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function setShortBreak() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 5;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'ShortBreak'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '05';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function setLongBreak() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 15;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'LongBreak'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '15';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}


//play-button turns into pause button, when it's clicked
function playVisibility() {
    document.getElementById("play").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility = "hidden";
}




//starts the timer
function timer() {

    document.getElementById("play").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility = "visible";

    
    playing = true;
    
    let time = startingMinutes * 60;

    setInterval(updateCoundtdown, 1000);
    time--;

    function updateCoundtdown() {
        if (playing) {
            let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
            let seconds = time % 60;

            seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

            currentMinutes = minutes;
            currentSeconds = seconds;

            document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
            document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            time--;
            console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds);
        } else {
            console.log('Currently:   ' + currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds)
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

#play {
    visibility: visible;
    position: inherit;
    top: calc(50% - 40px);
    left: 10%;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
#play:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

#pause {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: inherit;
    top: calc(50% - 40px);
    left: 10%;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
#pause:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

.play_img {
    height: 50px;
}

.pause_img {
    height: 50px;
}

.controls {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: 25em;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
}

#timer {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 175px);
    top: 16em;
    height: 120px;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
}

#minutes {
    position: inherit;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

#seconds {
    position: inherit;
    left: 200px;
    top: 5%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

#doppelpunkt {
    position: inherit;
    left: 160px;
    top: 1%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    top: 5em;
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#work {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(20% - 70px);
}


#work:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#work:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


#short_break {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(50% - 70px);
}

#short_break:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#short_break:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


#long_break {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(80% - 70px);
}

#long_break:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#long_break:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

::selection {
    background: transparent;
}




@media (max-height: 520px) {
    .controls {
        top: 6.8em;
        left: calc(62.7% - 50px);
    }
    #timer {
        top: 8em;
        left: calc(46% - 175px)
    }
    .header {
        top: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <button id="timer">
        <div id="minutes">25</div> 
        <div id="seconds">00</div> 
        <div id="doppelpunkt"> : </div>
    </button>

    <header class="header">
        <button id="work" onclick="setWork()">Work</button>
        <button id="short_break" onclick="setShortBreak()">Short Break</button>
        <button id="long_break" onclick="setLongBreak()">Long Break</button>
    </header>
    <nav class="controls">
        <button id="play" onclick="timer();"><img class="play_img" src="play.png"></button>
        <button id="pause" onclick="playVisibility(); playing = false"><img class="pause_img" src="pause.png"></button>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run `timer()` (click the play button), `setInterval(updateCoundtdown, 1000);` gets called again and `updateCoundtdown()` keeps getting called multiple times per second.

You need to clear the previous interval before you start a new one.

```js
let updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle = null;
// ...
function playVisibility() {
    // on pause clear the interval.
    if (updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle !== null) {
        clearInterval(updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle);
        updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle = null;
    }
    // ...
}

function timer() {
    // ...
    // if old interval is still running for some reason, clear it
    if (updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle !== null) {
        clearInterval(updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle);
    }
    updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle = setInterval(updateCoundtdown, 1000);
    // ...
}
```

```js
let timerSelection = 'Work';
let startingMinutes = 25;
let startingSeconds = 0;
let timerRunning;
let stopTimer;
let playing = false;
let currentMinutes;
let currentSeconds;
let updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle = null;

//sets the correct timer duration
function setWork() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 25;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'Work'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '25';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function setShortBreak() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 5;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'ShortBreak'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '05';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function setLongBreak() {
    if (playing == false) {
        startingMinutes = 15;
        startingSeconds = 0;
        timerSelection = 'LongBreak'
        document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = '15';
        document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = '00';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}


//play-button turns into pause button, when it's clicked
function playVisibility() {
    clearInterval(updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle);
    document.getElementById("play").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility = "hidden";
}




//starts the timer
function timer() {

    document.getElementById("play").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pause").style.visibility = "visible";

    
    playing = true;
    
    let time = startingMinutes * 60;
    if (updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle !== null) {
        clearInterval(updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle);
    }
    updateCoundtdownIntervalHandle = setInterval(updateCoundtdown, 1000);
    time--;

    function updateCoundtdown() {
        if (playing) {
            let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
            let seconds = time % 60;

            seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

            currentMinutes = minutes;
            currentSeconds = seconds;

            document.querySelector("#minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
            document.querySelector("#seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            time--;
            console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds);
        } else {
            console.log('Currently:   ' + currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds)
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}

#play {
    visibility: visible;
    position: inherit;
    top: calc(50% - 40px);
    left: 10%;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
#play:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

#pause {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: inherit;
    top: calc(50% - 40px);
    left: 10%;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
#pause:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

.play_img {
    height: 50px;
}

.pause_img {
    height: 50px;
}

.controls {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: 25em;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
}

#timer {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 175px);
    top: 16em;
    height: 120px;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
}

#minutes {
    position: inherit;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

#seconds {
    position: inherit;
    left: 200px;
    top: 5%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

#doppelpunkt {
    position: inherit;
    left: 160px;
    top: 1%;
    color: rgb(16, 203, 131);
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 250px);
    top: 5em;
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #cccccc10;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#work {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(20% - 70px);
}


#work:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#work:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


#short_break {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(50% - 70px);
}

#short_break:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#short_break:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


#long_break {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 140px;
    position: inherit;
    left: calc(80% - 70px);
}

#long_break:focus {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}
#long_break:hover {
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}


button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.527);
}

::selection {
    background: transparent;
}




@media (max-height: 520px) {
    .controls {
        top: 6.8em;
        left: calc(62.7% - 50px);
    }
    #timer {
        top: 8em;
        left: calc(46% - 175px)
    }
    .header {
        top: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <button id="timer">
        <div id="minutes">25</div> 
        <div id="seconds">00</div> 
        <div id="doppelpunkt"> : </div>
    </button>

    <header class="header">
        <button id="work" onclick="setWork()">Work</button>
        <button id="short_break" onclick="setShortBreak()">Short Break</button>
        <button id="long_break" onclick="setLongBreak()">Long Break</button>
    </header>
    <nav class="controls">
        <button id="play" onclick="timer();"><img class="play_img" src="play.png"></button>
        <button id="pause" onclick="playVisibility(); playing = false"><img class="pause_img" src="pause.png"></button>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How would you do that, so that the timer resumes at the point where it was stopped. Becuase now it restarts from where it was set in the beginning. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: You are resetting the time with `let time = startingMinutes * 60;` each time you resume.